# Angular UI bootstrap modal, ng-click entry argument is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello I am using angular ui bootsrap modal. And I have multiple buttons on there, but I am using one single method in ng-click, with different input argument.
The problem is that in the controller side, that input argument is always undefined

Here is part of the code:
The modal controller:

```
controller('MyModalController', [ '$scope', '$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

        $scope.keyPressed = function (key) {
            console.log(key);
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

    } ])
```

And the template that I am using for the modal:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-click="keyPressed(1)"><span>1</span></td>
    <td ng-click="keyPressed(2)"><span>2</span></td>
    <td ng-click="keyPressed(3)"><span>3</span></td>
    <td ng-click="keyPressed(4)"><span>4</span></td>
    <td ng-click="keyPressed(5)"><span>5</span></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Take a look on this Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/oNygS5pw2aNtTUpsnWHY?p=preview. Be sure that you have proper angular version and other stuff valid

Comment: After inspecting my code, I have noticed that I had caching problem with Chrome, funny thing never happened this before and now I have to clear the cache for every change I make

Answer (score 0):

if the number that you pass to the method is a sample of what you want to pass to the function, you have to bind it like that way:

```
<td ng-click="keypressed(1)"><span>{{1}}</span></td>
```

Comment: No that is not working, I am just trying to send 1 as an example

Comment: to be clear, when you click you want the argument to be print in the console right? nikolacoo i have write a lot of methods like this, and they always work, it's strange that it didn't work for you, maybe there's something wrong elsewhere, could you link a plunker or a fiddle?

Comment: at the end it was caching problem, see the answer that I have posted

Answer (score 0):

There was a caching problem, strange that now I have to clear the cache every single time I make a change and previously I didn't have this issue